# export pdl() only from perl PDL

Tags: perl, export, pdl

I want to export only the `pdl()` function from `PDL` to avoid namespace collision with other automatically exported functions such as `max`, `median`, `sum`, `intersect` etc. However, when I tried

```
use PDL qw(pdl);
```

it doesn't work as the aforementioned functions still get exported (and I get warnings on functions being redefined).

On the other hand, if I do

```
use PDL qw();
```

The collision doesn't happen. But when I try to use the `pdl()` function in the program via `PDL::pdl()`, it fails with this error message:

```
Can't call method "new" on unblessed reference at Basic/Core/Core.pm.PL (i.e. PDL::Core.pm) line 934.
```

Also, I tried inside the script

```
{
     require PDL;
     pdl();
}
```

I get the same error message.

Can someone advice on how I can export pdl() only? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SYNOPSIS
>        use PDL; # Is equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
>    use PDL::Core;
>    use PDL::Ops;
>    use PDL::Primitive;
>    use PDL::Ufunc;
>    use PDL::Basic;
>    use PDL::Slices;
>    use PDL::Bad;
>    use PDL::MatrixOps;
>    use PDL::Math;
>    use PDL::Version;
>    use PDL::IO::Misc;
>    use PDL::IO::FITS;
>    use PDL::IO::Pic;
>    use PDL::Lvalue;
> ```

I guess if you only import PDL::Core, you'll get only the functions in this module.

Comment: No, do not just import PDL::Core. Many of these modules assume that the others are loaded, so you have to pull in the whole thing with `use PDL`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually a bit surprised that `use PDL qw()` does anything different from `use PDL`. In fact, I don't see how it can: the code from `PDL::import` doesn't pay attention to its arguments. A different module was created for this very purpose called `PDL::Lite`, which is equivalent to:

```
use PDL::Core '';
use PDL::Ops '';
use PDL::Primitive '';
use PDL::Ufunc '';
use PDL::Basic '';
use PDL::Slices '';
use PDL::Bad '';
use PDL::Version;
use PDL::Lvalue;
```

Some of the extras from the usual `use PDL` are cut out, and none of the functions are imported. (`PDL::Lvalue` and `PDL::Version` do not export anything.)

On to your second question, when you `use PDL::Lite`, you can still get at the `pdl` constructor with `PDL->pdl(1, 2, 3)`. You cannot say `PDL::pdl(1, 2, 3)` because the constructor is actually defined in the `PDL::Core` package. Go figure. So, `PDL::Core::pdl(1, 2, 3)` does what you meant, but is not the obvious choice.